# select into temporary table repeatedly

Tags: sql, select

HI,

how can I select repeatedly into the same temporary table and then return the full outcome.

something like

```
select 
   col1, 
   col2 
into #temp 
where 
   col4="abc" 
   and col5=10
select 
   col1, 
   col10 
into #temp 
where 
   col4="dbe" 
   and col5=15
select * from #temp
```

I tried it, and it returned only the first part.

Comment: You should have got an error from that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    /*First one creates the table*/ 
   select 
       col1, 
       col2 
    into #temp 
    from something  
    where 
       col4="abc" 
       and col5=10

/*Now insert into the table that you just created*/     
    insert into #temp 
    select 
       col1, 
       col10 
    from something  
    where 
       col4="dbe" 
       and col5=15
    select * from #temp
```

You could also do

```
select 
       col1, 
       col2 
    into #temp FROM (
   select 
       col1, 
       col2 
    from something       
    where 
       col4="abc" 
       and col5=10
union all
    select 
       col1, 
       col10 
    from something         
    where 
       col4="dbe" 
       and col5=15) derived
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I never heard of union before, sounds the way to go, without really needing a temp table

Comment: @Charbel - Ah If the purpose of the temp table was just to consolidate the results then definitely you should use `UNION ALL` directly.

Answer (score 0):

The above code should end up in error.
You should insert into after the first select into.
Try this:

```
 select 
       col1, 
       col2 
    into #temp 
    where 
       col4="abc" 
       and col5=10;
    insert into #temp 
    select 
       col1, 
       col10 
    where 
       col4="dbe" 
       and col5=15;

    select * from #temp
```